# Vue 2 AOT ahead of time compilation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to understand Vue. Coming from angular2, I wanted to know if this documentation from Vuejs 2 is equivalent to angular2's AOT:

> When using vue-loader or vueify, templates inside *.vue files are pre-compiled >into JavaScript at build time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Using vue-loader or vueify will accomplish the same as AOT:

> vue-loader and vueify supports AoT out of the box - which means any project scaffolded with vue-cli are already using AoT.

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4272